Should my wife mention me as a dependent in her UK visa application if she's sponsoring my trip?
My spouse and I are planning a trip to the UK in June to celebrate our 5th wedding anniversary. However, a significant portion of my income goes towards our home loan EMIs, leaving me with limited disposable income. On the other hand, my wife is financially stable, and her income along with bank statements is sufficient to cover our trip expenses. We have decided that she will sponsor my UK trip.
In this scenario, should my wife mention me as a dependent in her UK visa application, even though I am not legally considered a dependent in our day-to-day lives? Additionally, should we both explain this arrangement in our respective cover letters for the visa application?
Any insights or experiences regarding similar situations would be appreciated.

If you are married, would it not be more usual to see your combined incomes as the income for the couple and the payments for the house as being paid out of that combined incomes, even when in practice the payments are made from one bank account?

See this question for how to apply as a family, with your wife as the primary applicant cross-referencing the applications. You’re not a ‘dependent’ as far as a Visitor visa goes

You’re over-thinking this IMHO.
You’re not a ‘dependent’ as far as a Visitor visa goes. You’re married, applying for a visa with your wife for a joint trip, and can show you have stable incomes and sufficient combined surplus funds for the trip.
The situation where one married partner ostensibly has more available funds than the other due to the way the couple chooses to split their joint living expenses is common and will not be a surprise to UKVI.
The solution is for your wife to apply as the primary applicant, cross-referencing her application to yours as described in this question. You can provide an explanation in the ‘additional comments’ section of the application and/or in a covering letter.
